Pyspark Data frame not returning rows having value more than 8 digits
I have created a sample data frame in Pyspark and the ID column contains a few values having more than 8 digits number. But it returns only those rows having less than 8 digits values in ID field. Can anyone please suggest how to write a proper code that will return all the values if the condition is matched.
# importing sparksession from pyspark.sql module 
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession 
  
# creating sparksession and giving an app name 
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('sparkdf').getOrCreate() 
data = [["2116722", "sravan", "company 1"], 
        ["2716722", "ojaswi", "company 2"], 
        ["2119722", "bobby", "company 3"], 
        ["21156311722", "sravan", "company 1"], 
        ["21422", "ojaswi", None], 
        ["2216722", "rohith", "company 2"], 
        ["3116722672", "gnanesh", "company 1"], 
        ["2156722", None, "company 2"], 
        ["4115666122", "bobby", "company 3"], 
        ["21190745", "rohith", "company 2"]] 
  
# specify column names 
columns = ['ID', 'Employee NAME', 'Company Name'] 
  
# creating a dataframe from the lists of data 
dataframe = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns) 
dataframe.where(dataframe["ID"] > 100000).show()


Output:
+--------+-------------+------------+
|      ID|Employee NAME|Company Name|
+--------+-------------+------------+
| 2116722|       sravan|   company 1|
| 2716722|       ojaswi|   company 2|
| 2119722|        bobby|   company 3|
| 2216722|       rohith|   company 2|
| 2156722|         NULL|   company 2|
|21190745|       rohith|   company 2|
+--------+-------------+------------+

Expected Output
+--------+-------------+------------+
|      ID|Employee NAME|Company Name|
+--------+-------------+------------+
| 2116722|       sravan|   company 1|
| 2716722|       ojaswi|   company 2|
| 2119722|        bobby|   company 3|
| 2216722|       rohith|   company 2|
| 2156722|         NULL|   company 2|
|21190745|       rohith|   company 2|
|21156311722|    sravan|   company 1|
|4115666122|      bobby|   company 3| 
|3116722672|    gnanesh|   company 1|
+--------+-------------+------------+



TLDR, Just cast to decimal before filtering; it should work as expected.
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

dataframe.printSchema()
dataframe\
.withColumn("ID",F.expr("CAST(ID AS Decimal(30,0))"))\
.where(F.col("ID") > 100000)\
.show()

Output:
root
 |-- ID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Employee NAME: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Company Name: string (nullable = true)

+-----------+-------------+------------+
|         ID|Employee NAME|Company Name|
+-----------+-------------+------------+
|    2116722|       sravan|   company 1|
|    2716722|       ojaswi|   company 2|
|    2119722|        bobby|   company 3|
|21156311722|       sravan|   company 1|
|    2216722|       rohith|   company 2|
| 3116722672|      gnanesh|   company 1|
|    2156722|         NULL|   company 2|
| 4115666122|        bobby|   company 3|
|   21190745|       rohith|   company 2|
+-----------+-------------+------------+

This is because the datatype of ID is String, which will be cast to int by default - and bigger values might not get accommodated to Int.
This is evident if we check the Analyzed Logical Plan:
dataframe.where(dataframe["ID"] > 100000).explain(True)

Output (See cast(ID#0 as int)):
== Parsed Logical Plan ==
'Filter (ID#0 > 100000)
+- LogicalRDD [ID#0, Employee NAME#1, Company Name#2], false

== Analyzed Logical Plan ==
ID: string, Employee NAME: string, Company Name: string
Filter (cast(ID#0 as int) > 100000)
+- LogicalRDD [ID#0, Employee NAME#1, Company Name#2], false

== Optimized Logical Plan ==
Filter (isnotnull(ID#0) AND (cast(ID#0 as int) > 100000))
+- LogicalRDD [ID#0, Employee NAME#1, Company Name#2], false

== Physical Plan ==
*(1) Filter (isnotnull(ID#0) AND (cast(ID#0 as int) > 100000))
+- *(1) Scan ExistingRDD[ID#0,Employee NAME#1,Company Name#2]

If we try casting the column, we can see bigger numbers will be nulls.
dataframe.withColumn("ID_int",F.expr("CAST(ID AS INT)")).show()

Output:
+-----------+-------------+------------+--------+
|         ID|Employee NAME|Company Name|  ID_int|
+-----------+-------------+------------+--------+
|    2116722|       sravan|   company 1| 2116722|
|    2716722|       ojaswi|   company 2| 2716722|
|    2119722|        bobby|   company 3| 2119722|
|21156311722|       sravan|   company 1|    NULL|
|      21422|       ojaswi|        NULL|   21422|
|    2216722|       rohith|   company 2| 2216722|
| 3116722672|      gnanesh|   company 1|    NULL|
|    2156722|         NULL|   company 2| 2156722|
| 4115666122|        bobby|   company 3|    NULL|
|   21190745|       rohith|   company 2|21190745|
+-----------+-------------+------------+--------+

